# How to get last login Access Date and time

Tags: user-meta

I have seen similar question Here at [First](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130533/order-get-users-by-last-login-date-is-it-possible) and [Second](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199243/save-last-login-date-in-global-before-change-it). But these two are not close to my code.

Let  me show  my code here.

```
add_action('wp_login', 'set_last_login');

//function for setting the last login
function set_last_login($login) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);
    $curent_login_time = get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'current_login', true);
    //add or update the last login value for logged in user 
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql') );
    }
}
```

and I wrote a get function to get the login access time.  But its receiving the current login time due to the update after login.  Is there any way to change it. I need to show the last login time.

How can I extend this function? . I am expecting a suggestion or code help to do this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found answer by myself. Let's explore it with two user meta's  `current_login, last_login`.Lets see the code.

```
//function for setting the last login
function set_last_login($login) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);
    $curent_login_time = get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'current_login', true);
    //add or update the last login value for logged in user
    if(!empty($curent_login_time)){
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', $curent_login_time );
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'current_login', current_time('mysql') );
    }else {
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'current_login', current_time('mysql') );
        update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql') );
    }
}
```

This will helps you to save the current and last login times. you can write an get last time function to get last login time. Here I wrote an article regarding the Last login and its working [Kvcodes- How to set User Last Login Date and Time in WordPress Without Plugin](http://www.kvcodes.com/2015/12/how-to-set-user-last-login-date-and-time-in-wordpress/)